# "The JavaScript runtime exited unexpectedly" error when parsing through Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I have a function `getFnF()` that iterates through a Google Drive folder and all of it's subfolders. When `getFnF()` encounters a Google Sheets file, I have the script parse through that Google Sheets file and extract out any URL Links it finds using my function `getLinksFromSheet()`. The functions both work, but after about 10 minutes of iterating through the Drive folder and calling `getLinksFromSheet()` on the Google Sheets files encountered, I get a `The JavaScript runtime exited unexpectedly.` error. Does anybody have any ideas what would be causing this error? The Google Drive folder is quite large (~500 files total in the subfolders, ~75 of which are Google Sheets). Code below:

```
function getFnF(folder) {
  var folder= folder || DriveApp.getFolderById("0AFZNRhJpE8LKUk9PVA"); //hard goded DEP-Gotham folder
  
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var files=folder.getFiles();
  
  while(files.hasNext()) {
    var file=files.next();
    var firg=sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow() + 1,level + 1);
    firg.setValue(Utilities.formatString('File: %s', file.getName()));
    Logger.log(file.getName())
    //if (file.getMimeType() == 'application/vnd.google-apps.document') {getAllLinks(file.getId(), false);};
    //if (file.getMimeType() == 'application/vnd.google-apps.presentation') {getLinksFromSlides(file.getId());};
    if (file.getMimeType() == 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet') {getLinksFromSheet(file.getId());};
  }

  var subfolders=folder.getFolders() 
  while(subfolders.hasNext()) {
    var subfolder=subfolders.next();
    var forg=sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow() + 1,level + 1);
    forg.setValue(Utilities.formatString('Fldr: %s', subfolder.getName()));
    level++;
    getFnF(subfolder);
  }

  level--;
}

function getLinksFromSheet(sheetId){
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetId); 
 var sheets = ss.getSheets();
 var parentDocName = ss.getName();

 var destSs=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
 var destSh=destSs.getSheetByName('Extracted Links');
 
 sheets.forEach(sheet => {
  var rangeData = sheet.getDataRange();
  var lastColumn = rangeData.getLastColumn();
  var lastRow = rangeData.getLastRow();
  var searchRange = sheet.getRange(1,1, lastRow, lastColumn);
  //var rangeValues = searchRange.getValues();
  var rangeValues = searchRange.getRichTextValues();


    for (var i = 0; i < lastRow; i++){
      for (var j = 0; j < lastColumn; j++){
       
        const runs = rangeValues[i][j].getRuns();

        for (const v of runs) {
           var nextLink = v.getLinkUrl();
           if (nextLink != null) {
           var row = destSh.getLastRow() + 1;
           var r1=destSh.getRange(row, 1);
           r1.setValue(parentDocName);
           var r2=destSh.getRange(row, 2);
           r2.setValue(nextLink);
           };
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: It could just be out of time right?
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations

Comment: @MattKing I ran the script again, and this time I got the error after only 4 mins. Could there be a different cause? Also, is there any way I can update the script to make it run faster?

Comment: @GabrielTero, were you able to try my modifications below? it should be able to save you some time and make your script faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue stems most likely from exceeding the limitation of runtime execution.

You can use `getFilesByType` to further whittle down the list and save time. Also did modify a bit in your code but should be able to do the same thing. They should have comments above them. Kindly check.

#### Usage:

```
function getFnF(folder) {
  var folder = folder || DriveApp.getFolderById("0AFZNRhJpE8LKUk9PVA"); //hard goded DEP-Gotham folder

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  // limit files to only google sheets
  var files = folder.getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS);
  
  // assign getLastRow to lessen method calls
  var lastRow = sh.getLastRow();
  // initialize level value
  var level = 1;

  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    // I can use appendRow here, but I did't since column has a variable
    // and you might change it. Feel free to update if necessary
    var firg = sh.getRange(lastRow + 1, level + 1);
    firg.setValue(Utilities.formatString('File: %s', file.getName()));
    getLinksFromSheet(file.getId()); 
    // iterate lastRow
    lastRow++;
  }

  var subfolders = folder.getFolders()
  while (subfolders.hasNext()) {
    var subfolder = subfolders.next();
    // I can use appendRow here, but I did't since column has a variable
    // and you might change it. Feel free to update if necessary
    var forg = sh.getRange(lastRow + 1, level + 1);
    forg.setValue(Utilities.formatString('Fldr: %s', subfolder.getName()));
    level++;
    getFnF(subfolder);
    // iterate lastRow
    lastRow++;
  }
  // not sure what this does but you can freely remove this if not being used
  level--;
}

function getLinksFromSheet(sheetId) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetId);
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  var parentDocName = ss.getName();

  var destSs = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var destSh = destSs.getSheetByName('Extracted Links');

  sheets.forEach(sheet => {
    // getDataRange already gets all the data
    var rangeData = sheet.getDataRange();
    // Flatten 2d array
    var rangeValues = rangeData.getRichTextValues().flat();
    
    rangeValues.forEach(v => {
      var link = v.getLinkUrl();
      if(link)
        // Use appendRow instead. Adjust array if needed to be in a different column.
        destSh.appendRow([parentDocName, link]);
    });
  });
}
```

#### Run time difference:

[image: diff]

The 6-second runs is the optimized one above while the 7-second runs is your code.

#### Test Conditions:

- Two sheet files in parent folder, one sheet file in 1 sub-folder:
- Each spreadsheet has 2 sheets, each sheet has 1 link.
- Parent folder has one non-sheet file.

#### Note:

- Given the significant runtime difference on a lesser number of files, certainly this will have greater impact on a huge number of files.
- If you want to include other type of files, then you need to create a separate loop to process each filetype if you have different type of process for each.
- You can also join 2 `getFilesByType` outputs into 1 array but getting links from different file types might vary so separate loop will be much safer.

Answer (score 0):

To get around the time problems you are having, I'd suggest one script to write all the spreadsheet ids and then another script to go down and process them (run getLinksFromSheet()) a line at a time and then mark each line as done so you can rerun it until you can finish.

Getrichtextvalue > getlinkURL is just slowwwwwwwww and you can't get around that.

Answer (score 0):

I think this could also be a memory size, or too much data in a single variable type of issue.  I'm getting the same error after seconds of starting a debugging session, but no indication of what is causing it.